# fill-in-the-blank induction proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, binary, recursion

I'm stuck at homework task I'm working on. I would really appreciate some help.

Here is the task:

> Let $f$ be a function on binary numbers defined recursively as follows.
>
> 1. $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$
> 2. $f(b0) = f(b)1$ , where $b$ is a binary number
> 3. $f(b1) = f(b)0$, where $b$ is a binary number
>
> The following is a proof by induction that $f(f(b)) = b$ for all binary numbers $b$. 
>   Find out what should be in the empty boxes below.
>
> **Basic-step**. It is the $1_____$ which holds for $b = 0$ and $b = 1$ By inserting $0$ for
>   $b$, we get $f(f(0)) = 0$ The following calculation shows that this is
>   true.
>
> - $f(f(0)) = f(1)$ at point $1$ in the definition of $f$,
> - $= 0$ at point $1$ in the definition of $f$
>
> By inserting $1$ for $b$, we get $f(f(1)) = 1$. The following calculation
>   shows that this is true.
>
> - $f (f (1)) = f (0)$ at point $1$ in the definition of $f$
> - = $1$ at point $1$ in the definition of $f$
>
> $2_____$**step**. Assume that the statement holds for a binary number $b$, that
>   is, $f(f(b)) = b$ which is $3_____$, and from this, we must show that the $4_____$ 
>   holds for a binary number $bx$, that is $f(f(bx))$ = $5_____$, where $x$ is either $0$
>   or $1$ We have two cases, one for $x = 0$ and one for $x = 1$
>
> If $x = 0$ we get the following.
>
> - $f(f(b0)) = f(f(b)1)$ at $6_____$ in the definition of $f$
> - $= f(f(b))0$ at point $3$ in the definition of $f$
> - $= b0$ by induction hypothesis
>
> If $x = 1$, we get the following-
>
> - $f(f(b1)) =$ $f$($7_____$) at $8_____$ in the definition of $f$
> - $= f(f(b))1$ at point $2$ in the definition of $f$
> - $= b1$ by induction hypothesis
>
> **At** $9_____$ **it follows that** $10_____$ **for all binary numbers** $b$.

**Edit:**

I tried solving this task, would appreciate if someone could check if I've done this correctly:

> 1. $f(f(b))$
> 2. Induction-step
> 3. $f(b)$
> 4. $f(f(bx))$
> 5. $bx$
> 6. point $2$
> 7. $f(f(b)0)$
> 8. point $3$
> 9. induction
> 10. assumption is true

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume those minus signs in the definition of $f$ are supposed to be $=$ signs?

Comment: yes, sorry, going to edit that now

Comment: Ugh. This is a regurgitation exercise. Most of it is about filling in the magical incantation words your textbook uses in its sample proofs by induction.

Comment: I suggest you place your textbook in the recycling bin for appropriate disposal.

Comment: If the notes don't include the appropriate vocabulary, you could try looking up "mathematical induction" on Wikipedia, MathWorld, ProofWiki, etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. O.K.
2. O.K. (technically, just *induction*, because you already have *step*).
3. I don't think so, but I'm not sure what your book wants from its clairvoyant readers. Maybe *the statement we need to prove*?
4. I think they want *assumption*, because $f(f(b))$ by itself means nothing.
5. O.K.
6. O.K.
7. O.K.
8. O.K.
9. Might be *induction step*.
10. O.K.

I will quote [dfeuer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17596/dfeuer), because it is pity that this remains only in the comments:

> I suggest you place your textbook in the recycling bin for appropriate disposal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear
what they mean by
"$f(b0) = f(b)1$"
and
"$f(b1) = f(b)0
$".
Do they mean
$f(2b) = 2f(b)+1$
and
$f(2b+1) = 2f(b)$?
This could be written as
$f(n) 
= f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)
+1 - (n \mod 2)
$

This does not agree with
your question
(unless I misunderstand)
because of this:

Let's compute
the first few
$f(n)$.
Since $f(0) = 1$
and
$f(1) = 0$,
$f(2) = 2f(1)+1=1$,
$f(3) = 2f(1) = 0$,
$f(4) = 2f(2)+1 = 3$,
$f(5) = 2f(2) = 2$,
$f(6) = 2f(3)+1 = 1$,
$f(7) = 2f(3) = 0$.

By induction,
$f(2^k-1)
=2f(2^{k-1}-1)
=0$.
Also,
$f(2^k)
=2f(2^{k-1})+1
=2^k-1
$.

Also by induction,
if $n \ge 1$ then
$f(n) \le n-1$.
Proof:
True for $n=1$.
If $n \ge 1$,
$f(2n)
= 2f(n)+1
\le 2(n-1)+1
= 2n-1$
and
$f(2n+1)
=2f(n)
\le 2(n-1)
=2n-2
\le 2n
$.

Looking at these,
$f(f(7))
=f(0)
= 1
\ne 7
$.

Staring at these,
I might conjecture that
$f(b)$ is the one's complement
of $b$ in binary
up to the highest 
$1$ digit in $b$.

That's all, folks.